# An error related to arrays in postgresql "ERROR: malformed record literal:"

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I am trying to get values from a table into an array and the array definition is different from the table's column definition. I have tried do cast but it is not working. Basically I need as an array (tab_small_str) the values in the table. Can someone please suggest on it:

```
CREATE TYPE tab_small_str AS (
  str CHARACTER VARYING(50)
);  

create table test_emp(emp_id integer, ename character varying (10));

insert into test_emp values(1,'a1')

insert into test_emp values(2,'a2')

insert into test_emp values(3,'a3')

CREATE OR REPLACE function test_fn () RETURNS VARCHAR[] as
$$
DECLARE
 v_ename tab_small_str[];
 i tab_small_str;
BEGIN

  SELECT   ARRAY(SELECT ename::tab_small_str FROM test_emp) INTO v_ename;

  RAISE INFO 'array is: %',v_ename;

  RETURN v_ename;

  FOREACH i IN ARRAY v_ename
LOOP 
   RAISE info 'value of ename is%', i;
END LOOP;

END;
$$
language plpgsql;

(function compiles fine).
select test_fn()

 --gives below error
    ERROR:  malformed record literal: "a1"
    DETAIL:  Missing left parenthesis.
    CONTEXT:  SQL statement "SELECT   ARRAY(SELECT ename::tab_small_str FROM test_emp)"
    PL/pgSQL function test_fn() line 7 at SQL statement
********** Error **********

ERROR: malformed record literal: "a1"
SQL state: 22P02
Detail: Missing left parenthesis.
Context: SQL statement "SELECT   ARRAY(SELECT ename::tab_small_str FROM test_emp)"
PL/pgSQL function test_fn() line 7 at SQL statement
```

Hi 404,
i modified as suggested:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function test_fn () RETURNS tab_small_str[] as
$$
DECLARE
 v_ename tab_small_str[];
 i  tab_small_str;
BEGIN

  SELECT   ARRAY(SELECT ROW(ename)::tab_small_str FROM test_emp) INTO v_ename;

  RAISE INFO '%',v_ename;

  FOREACH i IN ARRAY v_ename
LOOP 
   RAISE NOTICE '%', i;
END LOOP;

  RETURN v_ename;

END;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

it returns output as:

```
INFO:  {(a1),(a2),(a3)}
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function test_fn() line 9 at RAISE
NOTICE:  (a1)
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function test_fn() line 13 at RAISE
NOTICE:  (a2)
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function test_fn() line 13 at RAISE
NOTICE:  (a3)
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function test_fn() line 13 at RAISE
```

My question is why the output is surrounded by bracket - why not just a1 but (a1). Can you please suggest on it?

Comment: The type seems utterly useless to me. Getting rid of the type and using `v_ename varchar[]` would make much more sense - especially as your functions returns `VARCHAR[]` **not** `tab_small_str[]`

Comment: Thanks a_horse_with_no_name. Yes if I use v_ename varchar[] it does work fine. But in my actual work issue there is a type involved so I have to get solution keeping the type. I modified code to return the tab_small_str[] but it still gives error.

Comment: The best solution is to get rid of that type. It serves no purpose at all.

Comment: I do understand but I am working on the procedure that has some thousand lines and it uses the type. And I need to keep the type actually. So looking for some pointers on whether it is possible to manage with the type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your new type is not a "single field data type", for want of a better description, where you can cast something like a `VARCHAR(10)` directly to it; it's a ROW containing a single field. So something like `'blah'::tab_small_str` fails because it's trying to cast that text to the type which contains a field, rather than the field itself.

To resolve, using your existing query:

> `SELECT ename::tab_small_str FROM test_emp`

Change to:

```
SELECT ROW(ename)::tab_small_str FROM test_emp
```

As to why your results are surrounded by brackets: that is how a ROW or composite type is displayed when shown as a single field (or, non-expanded): for example, if you do `SELECT * FROM test_emp`, the `*` returns all fields individually as separate columns; however if you do `SELECT test_emp FROM test_emp`, that will return the table row unexpanded, so it will look like so:

```
(1,a1)
(2,a2)
(3,a3)
```

And composite types are exactly the same. `i  tab_small_str;` - think of `i` as `test_emp`, which contains fields which can be expanded. In your code you are printing the object `i`, rather than `i.*` or `i.str`. So change your code to:

```
FOREACH i IN ARRAY v_ename
LOOP 
   RAISE NOTICE '%', i.str;
END LOOP;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot 404! This looks like it but I have a question which I posted in my main  post.

Comment: @dbusern I've updated my answer, see if that works for you.

Comment: Awesome!! Thanks a lot!! I got the resolution of my doubts.